# How to define a certain order for tray icons in i3

Tags: i3, tray

I'm using the i3 window manager and I want to define some rules for tray icons order. By default, they are arranged in order of their application launch times. Is there are any way to configure an order for them? E.g.:

1. Show Thunderbird icon;
2. Then show nm-applet;
3. After that, display all other icons.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to manually arrange tray icons, as the creator of i3 points out [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/7j1nue/arrange_system_tray_icons/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/466z58/ordering_of_app_indicators/). You would have to make sure that they all start in a certain order.